# How to ignore custom html tag in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, facebook, vue.js

It is javascript source code for my vue component

```js
export default Vue.extend({
    template: `<fb:login-button ... ></fb:login-button>`
});
```

Vue show following warning in console

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly?

I want to know how to ignore `fb-login-button` tag in vue js?

Or how should I do?

Comment: Do you have to use the `<fb:login-button …>` element/syntax? The HTML5 compatible version of it just uses `<div class="fb-login-button" …>` – and since that’s a standard HTML element and not a custom one, I suppose it wouldn’t trigger that warning in the first place.

Comment: Also looking for an answer here, specifically for [A-Frame](https://aframe.io/docs/guide/) components. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Vue Version 2.0, You can use config's ignoredElements

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['menuitem']
```

It is already implemented in Vue 2.0, and will be implemented in Vue 1.1

resource: [vuejs issues 3090: Ignore some custom HTML components](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3090)

Comment: I believe you may also be able to use `v-pre` on the element.

Comment: I might suggest pushing the names onto the existing array. I tend to create, register, and exclude from the same file. By pushing onto the existing array, you avoid overwriting other peoples changes.